# I cannot access the raw PDO instance in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to access the raw PDO instance referring to this doc http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#accessing-connections by using this code `DB::connection()->getPdo();` to my controller. But I'm getting this error:

```
FatalErrorException in GeneralCategoryController.php line 24:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found
```

I've already tried to include this namespace `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` but still no result. 
Please note that I'm connected already to mysql database. 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

```
   <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\your_controller_path;
    
    use DB;// important
//then in
class your_controller extends Controller{
public function index(Request $request ){
    $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $query=$pdo->prepare("SHOW TABLES");
    $query->execute();//$query->execute(array($bindings ));
    while($row=$query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        //Use \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, \PDO::FETCH_OBJ    
        //echo $row->yourcolumnname;//its an object when \PDO::FETCH_OBJ
        echo $row[0]; //Indexed Array
                                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need either to reference it as `\DB` or add a `use DB;` at the top of your controller.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz! However it returns blank object.